# Which command after "git clone -n repository" to get same result as with "git clone repository"?

Tags: git

i am really beginer with Git and i want to do equivalent of this:

```
git clone repository dirname
```

But i want to do it in two phases:

```
phase1: git clone -n repository dirname
phase2: git "unknown command"
```

What is that "unknown command" to get exact result like with this one:

```
git clone repository dirname
```

?

I tried `git checkout` inside dirname but it does not work. It only lists files but after that dir remains empty (contains only `.git` dir). Documentation says it should be `git checkout <branch>` but i dont know which branch. I dont need to know branch if i do single phase:

```
git clone repository dirname.
```

- so what is two-phase equivalent to this without need to explicitly specify branch?

EDIT:

No `git checkout HEAD` nor `git checkout master` works - same result like with `git checkout` alone

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

Comment: Doing `git checkout HEAD` works for me, either your edit is wrong or you're using a weird repository with no default branch. Check the output of `git status`. But again, why are you wasting time doing this instead of learning something useful?

Answer (score 2):

The manual says `-n` means:

> No checkout of HEAD is performed after the clone is complete.

so the missing step when you use `-n` is "checkout of HEAD" ... so do that. i.e. `git checkout HEAD`

But **why** do you want to do this? If you're a beginner why aren't you trying to do something useful, instead of this?

Comment: The branch that gets checked-out by `git clone` (if you haven't specified one via `-b`) is found by a slightly complicated process that requires assistance from the server, so it can't be duplicated perfectly in a script.  You can usually get "close enough" by using `git ls-remote` and grubbing through the results to see which remote branch name the remote `HEAD` probably contains.  If the server on the remote is not new enough to support the "tell `clone` which branch for sure" extension, or the client doing the clone is too old to *use* the extension, that's how git does it.

Comment: torek: Interesting. What you think about "XOR hack" in my answer bellow?

Answer (score 2):

By trial and error i finaly find solution i hope its ok. From inside dirname call:

```
git checkout -- *
```

In other words, single phase:

```
git clone repository dirname
```

Seems to be equivalent to "two-phase":

```
git clone -n repository dirname
cd dirname
git checkout -- *
cd ..
```

-tested to work on Windows (git version 2.6.3.windows.1)

But interestingly on Linux with git version 1.7.10.4 this outputs error:
"error: pathspec '*' did not match any file(s) known to git."

So probably its some newer functionality not available in original git. Its documented here (See EXAMPLES section) : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

EDIT: 
Its more complicated. In some cases i get "error: pathspec '*' did not match any file(s) known to git." even on newer git on Windows. But in that cases simple `git checkout` works. Weird behavior. If `git checkout -- *` work then `git checkout` does not work and if `git checkout` work then `git checkout -- *` does not work. In other words `git checkout -- *` XOR `git checkout` work.    :-)

EDIT:
And if that "in-place" checkout does not work then method with temporary repository clone also work:

```
git clone dirname dirname_temp
rmdir "dirname_temp/.git"
xcopy /E /H /Y /C "dirname_temp/*" "dirname"
rmdir "dirname_temp"
```

Comment: Once again, **why?** Why use `-n` if you just want to check the files out anyway, and to do so end up doing another clone and copying from it?! Seems like a massive waste of effort.

Comment: You are expecting that checkout will be done immediatly after clone -n. Thats not the case. Between clone -n which means "i have it" and between checkout which means "i use it" can be any amount of time. At the time when "i have it" i dont need to store files which can be generated later (or never). And, yes, you are right, in most cases it is waste of effort. But thats life: waste of effort and then you die. :-)